# Outputting aggregated results in multiple lines by date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, aggregate-functions

I don't know how to appropriately title what I am after, but hopefully the question demonstrates what I am trying to achieve.

I have a query that is currently laid out similar to the below. I take start and end date inputs, structured using `with` in order to programmatically provide dates later in the process, separate from BigQuery.

```
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT
    CAST('START_DATE' AS DATE) AS start_date,
    CAST('END_DATE' AS DATE) AS end_date
),
complex_query_one AS (
    SELECT ....
    WHERE date_field BETWEEN dates.start_date AND dates.end_date
)
complex_query_two AS (
    SELECT ....
    WHERE date_field BETWEEN dates.start_date AND dates.end_date
)
complex_query_three AS (
    SELECT ....
    WHERE date_field BETWEEN dates.start_date AND dates.end_date
)

SELECT
SUM(complex_query_one.field1) AS c1field1_sum,
SUM(complex_query_one.field2) AS c1field2_sum,
AVG(complex_query_two.field1) AS c2field1_avg,
COUNT(complex_query_two.field1) AS c3field1_count,

FROM complex_query_one 
FULL OUTER JOIN complex_query_two ON complex_query_two.unique_id = complex_query_one.id
FULL OUTER JOIN complex_query_three ON complex_query_three.unique_id = complex_query_one.id
```

This outputs:

| c1field1_sum | c1field2_sum | c2field1_avg | c3field1_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| value | value | value | value |

At the moment I am running the query multiple times to obtain the results for given dates.

What I'd like to be able to do is output all the dates at once, like this:

| start date | c1field1_sum | c1field2_sum | c2field1_avg | c3field1_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| start_date1 | value | value | value | value |
| start_date2 | value | value | value | value |
| start_date3 | value | value | value | value |
| start_date4 | value | value | value | value |
| start_date5 | value | value | value | value |

How do I achieve this?

I was thinking I could lose the `WHERE` clause from the `complex_query_x` and do something like this for each aggregate function:

```
CASE WHEN dates.start_date1 = complex_query_one.start_date 
THEN SUM(complex_query_one.field1) AS c1field1_sum ELSE NULL END AS c1field1_sum
```

then `UNION ALL` with `dates.start_date2` `dates.start_date3` etc but that doesn't feel very efficient if it would even work at all.

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ff2834763fe522cbc814fdc0df18fd4b)

I don't have access to a bigquery setup.  This is just a rough idea, using MySQL.  The database isn't that important here, given basic standard SQL support is available.

Create a list of date ranges, with each range having a unique identifier.  I used `seq` as the identifier.  If the range list contains a unique list, we could use the ranges themselves to identify each row uniquely.

Each complex expression will (in some way) `GROUP BY`, `PARTITION BY` (or the equivalent) to handle multiple ranges in the logic.  Make sure to include the unique "test case" identifier (`seq`) in the result of each complex term.

Finally, the `FULL JOIN`s you showed will include the range identifier (`seq`, in this case) to associate related rows from each complex term in the result.

Here's a simple example:

| CTE term | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `dates` | list of date ranges |
| `testData` | Some test data |

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates0 (start_date, end_date) AS (
        SELECT CAST('2021-01-01' AS DATE), CAST('2021-02-01' AS DATE) UNION
        SELECT CAST('2021-02-01' AS DATE), CAST('2021-03-01' AS DATE) UNION
        SELECT CAST('2021-03-01' AS DATE), CAST('2021-04-01' AS DATE) UNION
        SELECT CAST('2021-04-01' AS DATE), CAST('2021-05-01' AS DATE) UNION
        SELECT CAST('2021-05-01' AS DATE), CAST('2021-06-01' AS DATE)
     )
   , dates (seq, start_date, end_date) AS (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY start_date, end_date)
             , start_date, end_date
          FROM dates0
     )
   , testData (thisDate, n) AS (
        SELECT CAST('2021-01-01' AS DATE) , 1   UNION ALL
        SELECT thisDate + INTERVAL '1' DAY, n+1 FROM testData WHERE n < 200
     )
   , complex1 AS (
        SELECT seq, start_date, end_date, COUNT(*) AS n
          FROM testData
          JOIN dates
            ON testData.thisDate >= start_date
           AND testData.thisDate <  end_date
         GROUP BY seq, start_date, end_date
     )
SELECT *
  FROM complex1 AS t1
  JOIN complex1 AS t2
    ON t1.seq = t2.seq
;
```

**The result:**

```
+-----+------------+------------+----+-----+------------+------------+----+
| seq | start_date | end_date   | n  | seq | start_date | end_date   | n  |
+-----+------------+------------+----+-----+------------+------------+----+
|   1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-02-01 | 31 |   1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-02-01 | 31 |
|   2 | 2021-02-01 | 2021-03-01 | 28 |   2 | 2021-02-01 | 2021-03-01 | 28 |
|   3 | 2021-03-01 | 2021-04-01 | 31 |   3 | 2021-03-01 | 2021-04-01 | 31 |
|   4 | 2021-04-01 | 2021-05-01 | 30 |   4 | 2021-04-01 | 2021-05-01 | 30 |
|   5 | 2021-05-01 | 2021-06-01 | 31 |   5 | 2021-05-01 | 2021-06-01 | 31 |
+-----+------------+------------+----+-----+------------+------------+----+
```